# FileNotFoundException. Не находит файл с данными при подключении jar-архива к проекту

Tags: java, исключения

Есть проект содержащий вспомогательные классы для решения различных задач. Maven подтягивает jar-архив из gitHub.

[Проект java-helper.tasks-solution](https://github.com/LugowoyKonstantin/java-helper.tasks-solution)

Написаны следующие классы:

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface CharacterReader {

    char[] read(String fileName);

    static char[] readCharacters(String fileName) {
        ArrayList<Character> charactersList = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            FileReader reader = new FileReader(ClassLoader.getSystemResource("characters/" + fileName + ".txt").getFile());
            int character;
            while ((character = reader.read()) != -1) {
                charactersList.add((char) character);
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return ArrayUtils.toPrimitive(charactersList.toArray(new Character[charactersList.size()]));
    }
}
```

Функционал метода `readCharacter(String fileName)` считывает данные(символы) из текстовых файлов, 
которые находятся в `resources/characters/...`
`english.txt`,
`russian.txt`
и т.д.

Класс `FillingArrayRandomStrings` реализует функциональность заполнения массива строками, созданными из случайных символов которые были считанными из файлов, которые находятся в `/resources/characters/...`

```
public class FillingArrayRandomStrings extends FillingArrayStrings {

private static final int DEFAULT_STRING_LENGTH = 10;

private CharacterReader characterReader;

private String fileName;

/**
 * Constructs a new object of the {@link FillingArrayRandomStrings} class.
 *
 * @param fileName The name of the file from which the random characters are read.
 */
public FillingArrayRandomStrings(String fileName) {
    this.characterReader = CharacterReader::readCharacters;
    this.fileName = fileName;
}

/**
 * Fills an object of the {@link Array} class with objects of the {@link String} class.
 * <p>The strings consist of random alphabetic characters that were taken from the file in the properties.
 *    The strings size is 10 characters.
 *
 * @param array The object of the {@link Array} class to be filled with objects of the {@link String} class.
 */
@Override
public void fill(Array<String> array) throws IllegalArgumentException {
    this.fill(array, DEFAULT_STRING_LENGTH);
}

/**
 * Fills an array with object of the {@link String} type.
 * <p>The strings consist of random alphabetic characters that were taken from the file in the properties.
 *    The strings size is 10 characters.
 *
 * @param strings The array to be filled with object of the {@link String} type.
 */
@Override
public void fill(String[] strings) throws IllegalArgumentException {
    if (checkNonNullArrayStrings(strings)) {
        this.initializeArrayElementsRandomStrings(strings, 0, DEFAULT_STRING_LENGTH);
    } else {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(new NullPointerException("The argument array is null."));
    }
}

/**
 * Fills an array with object of the {@link String} type.
 * <p>The strings consist of random alphabetic characters that were taken from the file in the properties.
 *    The strings size is 10 characters.
 * <p>The array is created based on the "lengthArray" parameter.
 * The parameter determines the length(size) of the created array.
 *
 * @param lengthArray The length(size) of the array to be filled with object of the {@link String} type.
 * @return Created and filled array with object of the {@link String} type.
 */
@Override
public String[] fill(int lengthArray) {
    String[] strings;
    if (checkLengthArray(lengthArray)) {
        strings = new String[lengthArray];
        this.initializeArrayElementsRandomStrings(strings, 0, DEFAULT_STRING_LENGTH);
    } else {
        strings = new String[DEFAULT_LENGTH_ARRAY];
        this.initializeArrayElementsRandomStrings(strings, 0, DEFAULT_STRING_LENGTH);
    }
    return strings;
}

/**
 * Fills an object of the {@link Array} class with objects of the {@link String} class.
 * <p>The strings consist of random alphabetic characters that were taken from the file in the properties.
 *    The strings size is parameter "lengthString".
 *
 * @param array The object of the {@link Array} class to be filled with objects of the {@link String} class.
 * @param lengthString Length of strings to fills.
 */
public void fill(Array<String> array, int lengthString) throws IllegalArgumentException {
    if (checkNonNullArrayObject(array)) {
        if (checkMinLengthStringToLessMaxLengthString(0, lengthString) && checkCorrectEndBoundOfLengthString(lengthString)) {
            String[] strings = new String[array.getLength()];
            this.initializeArrayElementsRandomStrings(strings, 0, lengthString);
            array.setArray(strings);
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("The value of the length of the string is not correct.");
        }
    } else {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(new NullPointerException("The argument object is null."));
    }
}

/**
 * Fills an array with object of the {@link String} type.
 * <p>The strings consist of random alphabetic characters that were taken from the file in the properties.
 *    The strings size is parameter "lengthString".
 *
 * @param strings The array to be filled with object of the {@link String} type.
 * @param lengthString Length of strings to fills.
 */
public void fill(String[] strings, int lengthString) throws IllegalArgumentException {
    if (checkNonNullArrayStrings(strings)) {
        if (checkMinLengthStringToLessMaxLengthString(0, lengthString) && checkCorrectEndBoundOfLengthString(lengthString)) {
            this.initializeArrayElementsRandomStrings(strings, 0, lengthString);
        }
    } else {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(new NullPointerException("The argument array is null."));
    }
}

/**
 * Fills an array with object of the {@link String} type.
 * <p>The strings consist of random alphabetic characters that were taken from the file in the properties.
 *    The strings size is parameter "lengthString" characters.
 * <p>The array is created based on the "lengthArray" parameter.
 * The parameter determines the length(size) of the created array.
 *
 * @param lengthArray The length(size) of the array to be filled with object of the {@link String} type.
 * @param lengthString Length of strings to fills.
 * @return Created and filled array with object of the {@link String} type.
 */
public String[] fill(int lengthArray, int lengthString) {
    String[] strings;
    if (checkLengthArray(lengthArray)) {
        if (checkMinLengthStringToLessMaxLengthString(0, lengthString) && checkCorrectEndBoundOfLengthString(lengthString)) {
            strings = new String[lengthArray];
            this.initializeArrayElementsRandomStrings(strings, 0, lengthString);
        } else {
            strings = new String[lengthArray];
            this.initializeArrayElementsRandomStrings(strings, 0, DEFAULT_STRING_LENGTH);
        }
    } else {
        strings = new String[DEFAULT_LENGTH_ARRAY];
        this.initializeArrayElementsRandomStrings(strings, 0, DEFAULT_STRING_LENGTH);
    }
    return strings;
}

/**
 * Fills an object of the {@link Array} class with objects of the {@link String} class.
 * <p>The strings consist of random alphabetic characters that were taken from the file in the properties.
 *    The strings size from parameter "minLengthString" to "maxLengthString".
 *
 * @param array The object of the {@link Array} class to be filled with objects of the {@link String} class.
 * @param minLengthString The starting (minimum) value of the string length.
 * @param maxLengthString The ending (maximum) value of the string length.
 */
public void fill(Array<String> array, int minLengthString, int maxLengthString) throws IllegalArgumentException {
    if (checkNonNullArrayObject(array)) {
        String[] strings = new String[array.getLength()];
        this.initializeArrayElementsRandomStrings(strings, minLengthString, maxLengthString);
        array.setArray(strings);
    } else {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(new NullPointerException("The argument array is null."));
    }
}

/**
 * Fills an array with object of the {@link String} type.
 * <p>The strings consist of random alphabetic characters that were taken from the file in the properties.
 *    The strings size from parameter "minLengthString" to "maxLengthString".
 *
 * @param strings The array to be filled with object of the {@link String} type.
 * @param minLengthString The starting (minimum) value of the string length.
 * @param maxLengthString The ending (maximum) value of the string length.
 */
public void fill(String[] strings, int minLengthString, int maxLengthString) throws IllegalArgumentException {
    if (checkNonNullArrayStrings(strings)) {
        if (checkMinLengthStringToLessMaxLengthString(minLengthString, maxLengthString)
                && checkCorrectEndBoundOfLengthString(maxLengthString)) {
            this.initializeArrayElementsRandomStrings(strings, minLengthString, maxLengthString);
        } else {
            this.initializeArrayElementsRandomStrings(strings, 0, DEFAULT_STRING_LENGTH);
        }
    } else {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(new NullPointerException("The argument array is null."));
    }
}

/**
 * Fills an array with object of the {@link String} type.
 * <p>The strings consist of random alphabetic characters that were taken from the file in the properties.
 *    The strings size from parameter "minLengthString" to "maxLengthString" characters.
 * <p>The array is created based on the "lengthArray" parameter.
 * The parameter determines the length(size) of the created array.
 *
 * @param lengthArray The length(size) of the array to be filled with object of the {@link String} type.
 * @param minLengthString The starting (minimum) value of the string length.
 * @param maxLengthString The ending (maximum) value of the string length.
 * @return Created and filled array with object of the {@link String} type.
 */
public String[] fill(int lengthArray, int minLengthString, int maxLengthString) {
    String[] strings;
    if (checkLengthArray(lengthArray)) {
        if (checkMinLengthStringToLessMaxLengthString(minLengthString, maxLengthString)
                && checkCorrectEndBoundOfLengthString(maxLengthString)) {
            strings = new String[lengthArray];
            this.initializeArrayElementsRandomStrings(strings, minLengthString, maxLengthString);
        } else {
            strings = new String[lengthArray];
            this.initializeArrayElementsRandomStrings(strings, 0, DEFAULT_STRING_LENGTH);
        }
    } else {
        strings = new String[DEFAULT_LENGTH_ARRAY];
        this.initializeArrayElementsRandomStrings(strings, 0, DEFAULT_STRING_LENGTH);
    }
    return strings;
}

private void initializeArrayElementsRandomStrings(String[] strings, int minLengthString, int maxLengthString) {
    char[] chars = this.characterReader.read(this.fileName);
    Random randomChar = new Random();
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < strings.length; i++) {
        for (int j = minLengthString; j < maxLengthString; j++) {
            stringBuilder.append(chars[randomChar.nextInt(chars.length)]);
        }
        strings[i] = stringBuilder.toString();
        stringBuilder.delete(0, stringBuilder.length());
    }
}

private static boolean checkMinLengthStringToLessMaxLengthString(int minLengthString, int maxLengthString) {
    boolean resultOfCheck = false;
    if (minLengthString < maxLengthString) {
        resultOfCheck = true;
    }
    return resultOfCheck;
}

private static boolean checkCorrectEndBoundOfLengthString(int lengthString) {
    boolean resultOfCheck = false;
    if ((lengthString > 0) && (lengthString <= Byte.MAX_VALUE)) {
        resultOfCheck = true;
    }
    return resultOfCheck;
}

}
```

Когда вызывается данный функционал в исходном проекте, то он без проблем подтягивает файлы и считывает символы.

А вот когда его подтягивает Maven к проекту с решаемыми задачами, то выдает исключение:

> FileNotFoundException.

Не находит файлы `/resources/characters/...` в jar-архиве.
В чем проблема?

Comment: Вы проверяли, есть ли ресурсы в собираемом jar?

Comment: Да, проверял. Он есть.

Comment: @ZMS Возможно, из-за <scope> в pom.xml? Указан compile. Но я ставил другие области, ничего не помогает.

Comment: А почему вы используете getSystemResource вместо getResource? Попробуйте getResourceAsStream  / getSystemResourceAsStream

Comment: Сейчас попробую. Будьте добры, если у Вас есть время, объясните, в чем разница между ними. Или в документации нормально это описано?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте использовать getResourceAsStream для чтения файла. Проблема возможна в том что URI файла пока он находится в jar становится что то вроде ...my_jar.jar!/resource/..., поэтому лучше взять просто потоком к этому файлу. Как смог так и попытался объяснить))

Comment: Именно такой URI файла и был при броске исключения. С окончанием "!". Сейчас перепишу код. Спасибо за помощь. Удачи.